# Cannot find model Entity name in fullstack

Tags: angular, spring-boot

> I am using fullstack  for my web application  angular+springboot ,when
>   i call my userEntity in my angular service class through local
>   host:8080 in that time i get the error userEntity cannot find
>
> ERROR in src/app/service/http-client.service.ts:12:32 - error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'UserEntity'.
>
> ```
> 12     return this.httpClient.get<UserEntity[]>('http://localhost:8080/user/get');
> ```
>
> UserEntity.java

```
package com.material.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="userentity")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

> UserController.java

```
package com.material.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.material.Entity.UserEntity;
import com.material.Repo.UserRepository;
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(path="user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<UserEntity> getUsers(){
        return userRepo.findAll();

    }
}
```

> http-client-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }
  getUsers()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserEntity[]>('http://localhost:8080/user/get');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not have `UserEntity` class, you need define class `UserEntity` in `.ts` file as

```
public class UserEntity{
    public id : number;
    public name: string;
    public password: string;
    //... remain property with UserEntity in java if having
}
```